# Preventing "warning: implicit declaration of function 'setlinebuf'..."

Tags: c, gcc, clang

Both Clang/LLVM and GCC show this warning. I am aware that headers must be included in order to use many functions, but `stdio.h` is included at the top of the file. I've used other functions (e.g., `setbuf()`) from the same header, and these work fine. Removing the header include causes errors and warnings to be thrown for these other functions, as expected.

I used `clang -MD -MF` to show included header files and checked `/usr/include/stdio.h`, which contains a prototype for `setlinebuf()`. I found one reference online to `unix.h`, but this doesn't appear to exist on my system.

I'm using Lubuntu 16.10 x86_64, Clang 3.8.1.

[**View source**](https://github.com/blieque/dtetris/blob/eacfe758ef51cf5d656ab08ee9e3fe7f8e70a084/dtetris.c): Include on line 1, function use on line 32.

Comment: You need to use the appropriate feature test macros for that function.  See `man setlinebuf`

Comment: ... [which is](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/setlinebuf.3.html) adding `#define _BSD_SOURCE` before any includes, to tell the library header files you want the BSD features (of which `setlinebuf()` is one).

Comment: suggest reading the man page for `setlinebuf()`  which includes this statement: `Feature Test Macro Requirements for glibc (see feature_test_macros(7)):

       setbuffer(), setlinebuf(): _BSD_SOURCE`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Include this *before* including `stdio.h`:

```
#define _BSD_SOURCE
```

`setlinebuf()` is not a standard C function and thus it may not be included by default in `stdio.h`.

But note that `_BSD_SOURCE` has been deprecated since glibc 2.20 and been superseded by `_DEFAULT_SOURCE`.

Comment: `_DEFAULT_SOURCE` did the trick, thank-you. Is there any drawback to doing this? Can the same not be achieved with standard C?  
Edit: "The setlinebuf() function is exactly equivalent to the call: `setvbuf(stream, NULL, _IOLBF, 0);`"

Comment: `setlinebuf()` is not in the C standard's library. Hence, it requires this additional macro to expose this interface. But you don't have to use this.
The man page even suggests an alternative using `setvbuf()`: `setvbuf(stream, buf, buf ? _IOFBF : _IONBF, BUFSIZ);`, which is part of C standard library and will not
require any additional macros. `setlinebuf()` is a more of convenience when available (I've used in my AIX days). But if you are writing for strictly standard complaint
or concerned about portability then you can easily avoid it.